# Question regarding taking input from a form in Django and transferring that data to a SQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I have 2 html/CSS forms set up and I also have a SQL database set up with values for everything on the forms. What steps would I need to do to ensure that the form and the database are linked?

P.S I already created a model and migrated stuff to the SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a model form.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

EG

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')


if request.method == 'POST':
    # A comment was posted
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        # Create Comment object but dont save to database yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()
```

and then render that from . That will have the necessary fiedlds.

Or you could create a form the has the fields you created the html/css forms for and then render it. When it is submitted, save it to the model individually
Eg

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    body = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea)

if request.method == 'POST':
    # Form was submitted
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        comment = Comment(
            name = cd['name'],
            email = cd['email'],
            body = cd['body'],  
        )
        comment.save()
else:
    form = EmailPostForm()
```

Comment: Got it set up like that, but when I submit something, it comes in as a GET instead of a POST any idea why or how to change that?

Comment: <form action="{..........}" method="post">. Along with the 'action attribute.. add the "method as shown.. i e in the template